# How to scrape a data from embedded Tableau report?

Tags: python, web-scraping, tableau-api

I need to company complaint index automatically. How can I scrape it from tableau report

For example
[link](https://content.naic.org/cis_refined_results.htm?TABLEAU=CIS_COMPLAINTS&COCODE=17230&:refresh)

I want to choose Policy type and then get Company Complaint Index. Or is there a way  to get the whole database?

I have tried to go to Tableau URL from Inspect page, but it says you should have permission to see the whole dashboard